# How to pull Coq source code from coqdoc pages

Tags: coq

There is a [specific library](http://color.inria.fr/doc/CoLoR.Util.Vector.VecUtil.html) that I want to use, but this question applies to other libraries as well. Many of them are available in the pretty-printed coqdoc format. What is the easiest way to pull a source code from them? Simply copying and pasting de-comments all the commentaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`coqdoc` parses Coq's `.v` files to extract the documentation information, and the language provides ways to "hide" parts of the `.v` file so it is not visible on the documentation. Trying to parse back the `.html` into `.v` might not be possible as is.

If you want the actual content of the file, the best way is to get Coq's source files and get it from here. If you don't want to download all of Coq's theories, you can pick the one you want at https://github.com/coq/coq/tree/trunk/theories

Comment: Note that in 8.5 the `.v` sources are installed along with the `.vo`s, so they are also available locally.